# didUpdateLocations gets called, but sends wrong location

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using core locations to get the location of the iphone. I also implemented the delegate protocols to my viewcontroller files, and created a CLLocationmanager object..

When I press a button (IBAction), I want the location get updated. The delegate gets called correctly. I can see that because a NSLog messages appears with the lat/long coordinates.

But when I change the location in the IOS simulator and try to access the location again with the button, the location output I get remains the same. I have to push the button again to get the correct location. Obviously I want the location to be right the first time I push the button

This is my button that triggers the delegate:

```
- (IBAction)getLocation:(id)sender {


[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

I have this piece of code in my viewDidLoad

```
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
```

This is my delegate method:

```
#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate 
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
 }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", [locations lastObject]);
CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];


if (currentLocation != nil) {
    _longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    _latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
   }
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

I'm running my code in Iphone 6.1 simulator..

Comment: Just a comment, in Objective C you can type if(currentLocation) instead of if (currentLocation != nil).

Comment: It's because you only start updating location when you press the button, and stop once you get the first location (the first location may not be the most accurate). You should keep the locationManager updating location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks to the comments below other answers..

I was waiting too short before calling the   `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];` method. The GPS just needed some more time..

So i just waited before doing the stopUpdatingLocation with an NSTimer. That did the job. Thanks to gWiz!

Answer (score 4):

From the Apple Reference: [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW8)

> Because it can take several seconds to return an initial location, the location manager typically delivers the previously cached location data immediately and then delivers more up-to-date location data as it becomes available.

Also answered in another stack overflow post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858548/cllocationmanager-holds-cache-value), use the timestamp property of CLLocation to filter out older cached location objects that are returned. I chose 15 seconds to be sure to differentiate a cached object but even only a few seconds will probably suffice:

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [[location timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow];
if (abs((NSInteger)timeInterval) < 15)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work if user change device's date and time

Answer (score 0):

I think , a different location has been setup as a mock location in your Xcode , that's what the simulator shows you. Check that out first. The simulator doesn't show you your current location , it shows the location that has been setup in Xcode as a mock location. Only device can show your real location. Hope it helps.

Comment: That's not the problem. I know that the location I imput in the simulator is fake. The problem is that when I change this mock location and update my location through the startUpdating method the location doesn't change with it

Comment: Then say you change from New York to London. What is shown after the first press? and after the second?

Comment: If it doesn't update , then try restarting Xcode , it should work.

Comment: Restarting Xcode doesn't work. When I change from New York to london the first time I press it still shows New York coordinates. The second time the coordinates get updated properly into london

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are trying to update the UI from inside `didUpdateLocations` which most certainly runs on another thread than the main thread.

Change this:

```
if (currentLocation != nil) {
_longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
_latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}
```

to this:

```
if (currentLocation != nil) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        _latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    });
}
```

Comment: This is not why the location manager shows a faked location, but it may also help for the purpose of updating the UI

Comment: @harrym17 The problem only seems to be UI updating, because the second time the button is pressed the correct location shows.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't change anything. Still have to push my 'get location' button twice to get the location I changed it to.

Comment: Try to do `NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]);` and see what you get, just to be sure it's not a UI issue.

Comment: I think it is not just a UI update problem. Because also the log message is wrong. When I update the location my program spits out a log message, but the lat/long coordinates are the same as the previous location. Only the second time I push the button the log message changes.

Comment: Try NOT calling `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];`. Do you get a second call to `didUpdateLocations`?

Comment: I think so yes, because the second time I call the delegate it spits out a NSLog that is defined in the delegate.

Comment: What can I use instead of [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation] to stop the delegate updating itself?

Comment: I think you should wait for the device to call `didUpdateLocations` for a small amount of time (call it a timeout) and then use stopUpdatingLocations. For example `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(stopUpdatingFunction) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];` and create a `-(void)stopUpdatingFunction { [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; }`

Comment: Wonderful, the waiting did the trick! Doesn't this make my app slow? And how can I know how long it takes to recieve GPS information on a real iPhone device? Because when I do this on a real iphone and the GPS info takes longer than 5 seconds, I will have the same problem right?

Comment: In my Apps I set a timeout (let's say 30 seconds) and show an Activity Indicator to the user saying: Waiting for location. I then check the accuracy if is what I want, and finally use the last location I got from didUpdateLocations

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code in   iOS6 Apple wants us to use didUpdateLocations instead of didUpdateToLocation

```
.h file


    CLLocationManager *locationManager;


.m File

  // get the current location latitude and longitude

    // locationManager update as location
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];


    locationManager.delegate=self;

    //Get user location
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    // Configure the new event with information from the location
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];

    NSLog(@"dLatitude : %@", latitude);
    NSLog(@"dLongitude : %@",longitude);


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

[locations lastObject];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

CLLocationManager does cache your location data. 
A useful approach would be to check the time interval between the updates.
You will get a timestamp for each location updates.
Compare the old and new location timestamps using this 
[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:oldLocation.timestamp] and discard those updates if interval is greater than 5 or so.